# Input line-by-line into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, java.util.scanner

I'm doing a program that needs to have as input a N by N matrix of integers. The input needs to be line-by-line using scanner in java and having space as delimiter.

Example of input:

0 0 1 0
1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0

at each new line it should add it to the matrix, any suggestions?

this is what i have:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("size: ");
    int size = scanner.nextInt();
    int[][] matrixAdj = new int[size][size];
    int x = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();


            String[] lineI = line.split(" ");


            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                matrixAdj[x][j] = Integer.parseInt(lineI[j]);
            }
            x++;
        }
```

thanks..

Comment: edited it, sorry about that

Comment: What's wrong with the code you currently have? (What do you expect to happen vs what's actually happening?)

Comment: As I press "enter" to insert a line it gives me an error inside the for loop as if lineI[j] were null. I guess the scanner is getting it as '\n' or something...

Comment: You would be correct. `nextInt` doesn't clear the `\n` from the `Scanner`. Take a look at [Dukeling's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18994294/758280).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the example input is:

```
4
0 0 1 0
1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0
```

If it's not, it should be since the first character you read is the size.

`nextInt` and `nextLine` don't work well together. `nextInt` doesn't move on to the next line, so you'll end up with an empty string on the first read of `nextLine`.

To fix this, either call `nextLine` once directly after `nextInt`:

```
int size = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // advance to next line
```

or use `nextLine` instead:

```
int size = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

or you can just repeatedly call `nextInt` and forget about `nextLine` altogether:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      matrixAdj[x][j] = scanner.nextInt();
   }
   x++;
}
```

although issues could be difficult to figure out if there's something wrong with your input.